# Making the changes in /etc/pulse/system.pa work

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, hdmi

I'm running pulseaudio in system mode. So I added a few changes to the `/etc/pulse/system.pa` file. I need to combine a few sinks for simultaneous audio output so I added those changes there.

```
load-module module-alsa-sink device=hw:0,0 sink_name=analog
load-module module-alsa-sink device=hw:0,3 sink_name=hdmi
load-module module-combine-sink sink_name=combined slaves=analog,hdmi
set-default-sink combined
```

When I try and restart pulseaudio with the following it fails.

```
sudo systemctl restart pulseaudio
```

The error says failed to initialize.

When I run the load-module commands in my terminal or in a separate script file they work fine. So it has to do with the system.pa file and I can't seem to find much documentation about this.